# How to build tensorflow native for android using clang toolchain?

Tags: android, tensorflow, bazel

Based on this [bazel using clang](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/817) , need to add command line option for setting android compiler option. How does this translate to `*.bzl` files, crosstool files in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

Bazel 0.4.5 and later support Android NDK clang via the `--android_compiler=clang3.8` build flag. Note that in NDK13, clang is the default (previous was gcc) so this flag is only needed for NDK12 and prior. No bzl or crosstool files necessary (although android_ndk_repository is actually generating a crosstool file under the hood).